# double installation MySQL on Win10

Tags: mysql, xampp

Some time ago I installed XAMPP on my win10 desktop (AMD Phenom, 8gb). The reason for this is that I want to do some wordpress development.

I now want to learn how to work with MySQL and Python. Do I now have to install a new version of MySQL that runs on Win10 or can I use the currently installation that runs under XAMPP? I understand that when using XAMPP I first have to start up the XAMPP server.

I do not want to experiment as I just reinstalled win10 since I got stuck installing so many application on it.

Is it just a matter of starting up XAMPP and then connecting the database with Python? Will Python recognise it?

All help is much appreciated,

Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the current instance and connect with Python.  As long as you have the username, password, and using localhost or an IP address all should go find.

Comment: that was quick. Thanks for this. So I can get to work. Great!